# Removing event listener using loop removes only last element's listener

Tags: javascript, events, removeeventlistener

I have 3 elemenets in HTML collection and attach onclick listeners to them using forEach loop

```
[].forEach.call(signBoxes, (e, i) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", callSetSign = () => setSign(signs[i]));
});

function setSign({ name, src }) {
  const sign = name;
  const Img = src;
  player1Choice.src = Img;
  [].forEach.call(signBoxes, (e, i) => {
    e.removeEventListener("click", callSetSign);
  });
  socket.emit("self-choose-sign", sign);
}
```

Adding listeners works fine, however when I try to remove them in the same way, only the last element's listener is removed. If I alter the function like this, i get the same result.

```
function setSign({ name, src }) {
  const sign = name;
  const Img = src;
  player1Choice.src = Img;
  signBoxes[0].removeEventListener('click', callSetSign)
  signBoxes[1].removeEventListener('click', callSetSign)
  signBoxes[2].removeEventListener('click', callSetSign) // only this one works
  socket.emit("self-choose-sign", sign);
}
```

Can someone explain this?

Comment: `callSetSign = () => setSign(signs[i])` <= this is replacing the value of `callSetSign` with a new arrow function every time it happens.  It will only point to the last arrow function assigned to it.  Which would only be on the last element iterated over as well.  Which would explain the behavior you are reporting

Comment: Appreciate quick answer, but if i declare callSetSign before a loop, is it possible to pass it a parameter without using bind, so i can remove listener later?

Comment: `function callSetSign () { return setSign(this); }` paired with `e.addEventListener("click", callSetSign);` I would imagine would allow you to do what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an element's `dataset` object to pass parameters of type `string` to the event handler.

Obviously attempts to place parameters on the function object will simply over-write a property of the same name, and the `.bind` method does not return the function it was called on. Attempts to pass parameters in a closure or by calling `bind`  will result in multiple handler function objects.

An untested example of the `dataset` approach:

```
[].forEach.call(signBoxes, (e, i) => {
  e.dataset.index = i;  // store index on element
  e.addEventListener("click", setSign);
});

function setSign() {
  const { name, src } = signs[this.dataset.index];; // lookup using index
  const sign = name;
  const Img = src;
  player1Choice.src = Img;
  [].forEach.call(signBoxes, (e, i) => {
    e.removeEventListener("click", setSign);
  });
  socket.emit("self-choose-sign", sign);
}
```

Comment: I was able to come up with unsatisfying solution, since i only had 3 elements i checked if `event.path[1].id` (id of the DOM element) was `someValue` then i would pass `setSign[correspondingValue]`. This wouldn't help me for long list. Your solution works and is much better. Don't even have to use dataset as it works with just `e.index`  as well .

Comment: @Zobla You can usually get away with treating an `HTMLElement` object as an ordinary JavaScript object and add new properties of any data type to it, Historically this has caused problems and is discouraged as being non standard. Since the `dataset` property is , defined in standards it remains predictable into the future.